# Using proc sql to remove duplicates when doing a fuzzy merge

Tags: sql, merge, sas

I have a file where the unique key is pt_num and date.

```
data person;
   input pt_num day ;
   format day date9.;
   datalines;
12 5
12 6
run;
```

I want to merge it with a file (clms) that has a series of claims throughout time. During the merge, I want to do a five-day lookback and only output the dx_cd once.

```
data clms;
   input pt_num clmdate dx_cd;
   format clmdate date9.;
   datalines;
12 3 1
12 5 1
12 6 2
run;
```

Currently, I am using a proc SQL merge and then removing duplicates with a proc sort.

```
proc sql;
  create table disease as 
    select p.pt_num, p.day, c.dx_cd from person P 
    left join clms C    
    on p.pt_num = c.pt_num and c.clmdate ge p.day-5 and c.clmdate le p.day;
quit;

proc sort data=disease nodupkey ; by pt_num day dx_cd; run;
```

Eventually, I make the file long using a data step and SAS arrays. The final output would look like this. A '1' indicates the dx occurred during the five-day look back and a '0' indicates it did not. The variable name would be the name that was in the row in the previous table.

```
data final;
     input pt_num clmdate dx_1 dx_2;
     datalines;
12 5 1 0
12 6 1 1
run;
```

These files are large (the nodup sort for one file takes 2 hours and I have to do this multiple times). I have been trying to no success to remove duplicates during the SQL step using the group by function. I would assume removing the duplicates during the SQL procedure would reduce time, but I could be wrong.

```
proc sql;
  create table disease as 
    select p.pt_num, p.day, c.dx_cd
    from person P 
    left join clms C    
     on p.pt_num = c.pt_num and
           c.clmdate ge p.day-5 and
           c.clmdate le p.day
    group by dx_cd
    order by pt_num, day, dx_cd;
quit;
```

I hope this explanation was clear. The purpose of this is to generate a list of covariates that will eventually be used to create a propensity score. The PS will be recalculated at various points, which is why I am creating a patient day file.

Thank you,
Laura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding DISTINCT to the SQL query, but not sure it will save you any time overall.

```
proc sql;
  create table disease as 
    select DISTINCT p.pt_num, p.day, c.dx_cd from person P 
    left join clms C    
    on p.pt_num = c.pt_num and c.clmdate ge p.day-5 and c.clmdate le p.day;
quit;
```

I would recommend [indexing](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lrcon/n06cy7dznbx6gen1q9mat8de6rdq.htm) your data by PT_NUM
A SASFILE statement will help speed up your process, if you have enough RAM to store the data.

**Use the [SASFILE](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/hosto390/n0vtt9hbew6jp4n1k4xyx7jkvgha.htm) Statement to Load a Frequently Used SAS Data Set into Memory**

> By default, any SAS data set that is processed by a SAS procedure or DATA step is closed at the conclusion of the procedure or step. This action causes the buffers to be released and any updated pages to be written to disk. If a subsequent procedure or step needs to read or update the SAS data set again, the same pages that were already in buffers might need to be read back from disk again. Such extra I/O can be avoided by specifying two SASFILE statements:
>
> - one statement to open or load the SAS data set before the procedures or DATA steps in which the data set is used
>   Note: The SASFILE statement loads the entire member into memory. That is, it ignores any previous setting of the OBS option.
> - a second statement to close the data set after its last use within the SAS session

Comment: The distinct does work fine for the fake data, but, for some reason, not the real data. Thank you for your suggestion. 

I looked at indexing to speed up merging. I understand that if you merge two files sorting was better (or equal) to indexing. 

I considered indexing the main data and then updating it with the extra columns (by pt_num & day-an equal number of obs), but from what I've seen that isn't a favored solution. And I don't know how to do it.

Right now I am merging the data files together using a double set. https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings14/1271-2014.pdf

Comment: I'm guessing your real data has more variables than the ones shown? And that those may not be duplicated identically?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize adding distinct in front of the select clause did it on all variables. I've only used distinct during count(distinct pt_num).